# Regular expression for user id

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions.

I have a requirement to write a regular expression with the following criteria

- User ID cannot be all numeric
- User ID cannot have special characters
- Minimum length of 8 characters
- Maximum length of 20 characters
- Can be all alphabetic
- Can be alphanumeric

I have written the following expression but it does not work

```
^[a-zA-Z\\d*]{8,20}$
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the error message? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Comment: if i give input as "aaaaaaaa123" it returns true, the actual output should be false.

Comment: Why `aaaaaaaa123` should be false?

Comment: sorry input "aaaaaaaa123" should return true but for my regex it returns false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
(?i)^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{8,20}$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fR4hZ4) of what works and what fails

- `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive
- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- the lookahead `(?=.*[a-z])` checks that we have at least one letter
- `[a-z0-9]{8,20}` matches 8 to 20 letters or digits (letters can be uppercase too)
- `$` asserts that we have reached the end of the string

Comment: the regular expression which you gave works well in java but in javaScript it fails.

Comment: Yes, `(?i)` doesn't exist in JS. To set the case-insensitive mode in JS, do it like this: `/^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{8,20}$/i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!\\d+$)\\w{8,20}$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fG8cR8)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code and check:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!\\d+$)\\w{8,20}$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Tryurcode4u");
    System.out.println("Input String matches regex - "+matcher.matches());
}
```